# update duplicate values conditionally in oracle/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to update the duplicate value in paid column if any sub marked as paid; then update the other sub with same customer

Here is the sample data:

```
DATE    Event_ID    EVENT   CUSTOMER    SUBSCRIBER  Paid
01/24/2011  3513709 Play 1  41285030    38803277    Y
01/24/2011  3513709 Play 1  41285030    45051523    N
01/24/2011  3513709 Play 1  41285030    45051523    Y
01/25/2011  3527194 Play 2  45568242    43673464    Y
01/25/2011  3527194 Play 2  45568242    45023437    N
02/03/2011  3622935 Play 3  19356414    43546915    Y
02/03/2011  3622935 Play 3  19356414    44981229    N
02/07/2011  3674946 Play 4  41240152    38744274    Y
02/07/2011  3674946 Play 4  41240152    44225340    Y
02/07/2011  3674946 Play 4  41240152    44820829    N
03/10/2011  4094832 Play 5  31485304    33260562    Y
03/10/2011  4094832 Play 5  31485304    43922788    Y
03/10/2011  4094832 Play 5  31485304    45022503    N
03/10/2011  4094832 Play 5  31485304    45022503    Y
03/10/2011  4094833 Play 6  31485304    33260562    N
03/10/2011  4094833 Play 6  31485304    43922788    N
03/10/2011  4094833 Play 6  31485304    45022503    N
03/16/2011  4167371 Play 7  19384295    32940366    Y
03/16/2011  4167371 Play 7  19384295    45002390    N
03/17/2011  4179070 Play 8  36882841    38554357    Y
03/17/2011  4179070 Play 8  36882841    44988521    N
```

Desired output should be like this:

```
DATE    Event_ID    EVENT   CUSTOMER    SUBS    Paid
01/24/2011  3513709 Play 1  41285030    38803277    Y
01/24/2011  3513709 Play 1  41285030    45051523    Y
01/24/2011  3513709 Play 1  41285030    45051523    Y
01/25/2011  3527194 Play 2  45568242    43673464    Y
01/25/2011  3527194 Play 2  45568242    45023437    Y
02/03/2011  3622935 Play 3  19356414    43546915    Y
02/03/2011  3622935 Play 3  19356414    44981229    Y
02/07/2011  3674946 Play 4  41240152    38744274    Y
02/07/2011  3674946 Play 4  41240152    44225340    Y
02/07/2011  3674946 Play 4  41240152    44820829    Y
03/10/2011  4094832 Play 5  31485304    33260562    Y
03/10/2011  4094832 Play 5  31485304    43922788    Y
03/10/2011  4094832 Play 5  31485304    45022503    Y
03/10/2011  4094832 Play 5  31485304    45022503    Y
03/10/2011  4094833 Play 6  31485304    33260562    N
03/10/2011  4094833 Play 6  31485304    43922788    N
03/10/2011  4094833 Play 6  31485304    45022503    N
03/16/2011  4167371 Play 7  19384295    32940366    Y
03/16/2011  4167371 Play 7  19384295    45002390    Y
03/17/2011  4179070 Play 8  36882841    38554357    Y
03/17/2011  4179070 Play 8  36882841    44988521    Y
```

Comment: previously using excel to do the job looking if someone can help to get sql query.

Comment: Does it have to check for the same EVENT and SUBSCRIBER as well as CUSTOMER?

Comment: in excel i used to check if customer is been charged for the event thru one subd other subs with same customer suld be taged as paid  i hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The gist of this is to

- Create a subselect with all customers who have a paid subscription
- `JOIN` this subselect back with your actual table on afformentioned customers
- Use this result in the `UPDATE` clause
- Only update where Paid is `N`

**SQL Statement**

```
UPDATE  YourTable
SET     Paid = 'Y'
FROM    YourTable t
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  Customer
            FROM    YourTable
            WHERE   Paid = 'y'
        ) c ON c.Customer = t.Customer
WHERE   Paid = 'N'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with a naive subquery:

```
update events set paid = 'Y' where event_id in (
    select event_id from events where paid = 'Y'
)
```

Comment: it worked but ran into other problem this query also updating record where event_id is same but customer is different. the result i was looking to find the duplicate event_ids and only update the paid column if the customer is same

Comment: Then you should have explained this in your question. Please put in more effort next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [Event], [Customer], SUM(CASE Paid WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Sum]
    FROM tmpTbl
    GROUP BY [EVENT], Customer)

UPDATE tmpTbl SET [Paid] = 'Y'
FROM tmpTbl JOIN CTE AS tbl ON tmpTbl.[Event] = tbl.[Event] AND tmpTbl.[Customer] = tbl.[Customer] AND tbl.[Sum] > 0
```

Sample data script

```
SELECT * INTO tmpTbl FROM (
SELECT GETDATE() -1 [DATE] ,3513709 [Event_ID],'Play 1' [Event],41285030 [CUSTOMER],38803277 [SUBSCRIBER],'Y' [PAID] UNION
SELECT GETDATE() -1 [DATE] ,3513709 [Event_ID],'Play 1' [Event],41285030 [CUSTOMER],45051523 [SUBSCRIBER],'N' [PAID] UNION
SELECT GETDATE() -1 [DATE] ,3513709 [Event_ID],'Play 1' [Event],41285030 [CUSTOMER],45051523 [SUBSCRIBER],'Y' [PAID] UNION

SELECT GETDATE() -2 [DATE] ,3527194 [Event_ID],'Play 2' [Event],45568242 [CUSTOMER],43673464 [SUBSCRIBER],'Y' [PAID] UNION
SELECT GETDATE() -2 [DATE] ,3527194 [Event_ID],'Play 2' [Event],45568242 [CUSTOMER],45023437 [SUBSCRIBER],'N' [PAID] UNION

SELECT GETDATE() -3 [DATE] ,4094832 [Event_ID],'Play 5' [Event],31485304 [CUSTOMER],43922788 [SUBSCRIBER],'Y' [PAID] UNION
SELECT GETDATE() -3 [DATE] ,4094832 [Event_ID],'Play 5' [Event],31485304 [CUSTOMER],45022503 [SUBSCRIBER],'Y' [PAID] UNION
SELECT GETDATE() -3 [DATE] ,4094832 [Event_ID],'Play 5' [Event],31485304 [CUSTOMER],45022503 [SUBSCRIBER],'N' [PAID] UNION
SELECT GETDATE() -3 [DATE] ,4094832 [Event_ID],'Play 5' [Event],31485304 [CUSTOMER],33260562 [SUBSCRIBER],'Y' [PAID] UNION
SELECT GETDATE() -3 [DATE] ,4094833 [Event_ID],'Play 6' [Event],31485304 [CUSTOMER],43922788 [SUBSCRIBER],'N' [PAID] UNION
SELECT GETDATE() -3 [DATE] ,4094833 [Event_ID],'Play 6' [Event],31485304 [CUSTOMER],33260562 [SUBSCRIBER],'N' [PAID] UNION
SELECT GETDATE() -3 [DATE] ,4094833 [Event_ID],'Play 6' [Event],31485304 [CUSTOMER],45022503 [SUBSCRIBER],'N' [PAID]) as tbl
```

Output

```
DATE    Event_ID    EVENT   CUSTOMER    SUBS    Paid
02/01/2012  3513709 Play 1  41285030    38803277    Y
02/01/2012  3513709 Play 1  41285030    45051523    Y
02/01/2012  3513709 Play 1  41285030    45051523    Y
01/31/2012  3527194 Play 2  45568242    43673464    Y
01/31/2012  3527194 Play 2  45568242    45023437    Y
01/30/2012  4094832 Play 5  31485304    33260562    Y
01/30/2012  4094832 Play 5  31485304    43922788    Y
01/30/2012  4094832 Play 5  31485304    45022503    Y
01/30/2012  4094832 Play 5  31485304    45022503    Y
01/30/2012  4094833 Play 6  31485304    33260562    N
01/30/2012  4094833 Play 6  31485304    43922788    N
01/30/2012  4094833 Play 6  31485304    45022503    N
```